# JOptionPane - Creating resizable text and GUI

Tags: java, swing, fonts, joptionpane

To increase the size of my text, I added this line of code

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new FontUIResource(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25)));
```

But when I make the size of my text too large, I can't resize the dialog. This becomes a problem when I have too much text on the screen, causing my GUI to be vertically larger than my screen, which ultimately stops me from being able to press the "x" button at the top, or any of the buttons that I have at the bottom of the screen. I want to be able to drag to resize my GUI, along with the size of the text inside. Is this possible to do? If not, how can I create a resizable GUI?

Another question I had was how to make JOptionPane full screen?

Comment: Put your text inside a `JTextArea`, put the `JTextArea` inside a `JScrollPane`, seed this as the "message" property to `JOptionPane`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by adding a listener before displaying the dialog and it will be called when added to the dialog and also when the dialog will  be visible.
With the help of Windows class

```
 Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(yourComponent);
```

If you want to use `setResizable()` method we need to typecast it to dialog

```
if (window instanceof Dialog) {
    Dialog dialog = (Dialog) window;
    if (!dialog.isResizable()) {
        dialog.setResizable(true);
    }
}
```

Here is a method that you can wrap your component in a scrollpane

```
private void showDialogRez(Component frame, final Component component) {
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(component);
    
    component.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {
        public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
            Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(component);
            if (window instanceof Dialog) {
                Dialog dialog = (Dialog) window;
                if (!dialog.isResizable()) {
                    dialog.setResizable(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, scrollPane);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

People tend to forget that `JOptionPane` is capable of more than just displaying text.  Passing a component as the `message` parameter will display the component directly on the resulting dialog.

The following is a slightly simplified example.  It loads text from an embedded text file (bring your own), which, for this example, is the New Hope script copied from https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html and displays it.

[image: Simple example]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(25, 50);
                ta.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25));

                String text = "";
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("Script.txt")))) {
                    String line = null;
                    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(1024);
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    text = buffer.toString();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                ta.setText(text);
                ta.setCaretPosition(0);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(ta));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The important part to note here is the line `JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(25, 50);`.  This is going to set up the "preferred scrollable size" of the text area, which the `JScrollPane` will use to make determinations about how much space it wants.

Try removing the parameters from `JTextArea` constructor and see the result for comparison.

Now, there are going to be limitations and you're going to have to find ways to balance your desires against what is physically possible with the hardware (screen) realestate that you have.

You can also do the same thing with a `JFrame`, so replacing the call to `JOptionPane` with something like...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Will give you a similar result.  In both cases the window is resizable.

You could got to a lot of hassle with calculating the available viewable space of the target screen and the desired size of the window and do lots of fudging, but in most cases, you just need to be thoughtful about what you're doing and work within some of the limitations you're presented with.